Finding the asymptotic rate of growth of a table of values using asymptotic analysis?
Note: This question is slightly different from this question since the emphasis is more on math than programming.
Suppose, using mathematica, we define entropy[k] where:

F[r_] is $F_r=\left\{c/t: c\in\mathbb{Z}, t\in\mathbb{N}, 0\le c\le t, t \le r \right\}$
S1[k] takes elements of F[r] with an even denominator
S2[k] takes elements of F[r] with an odd denominator
P1[k] takes the 2-d Euclidean distance between consecutive points, where the $x$-values of S1[k] are paired with $y=1$, and the $x$-values of S2[k] are paired with $y=0$
U1[k] multiplies all elements in P1[k] by a constant so they add up to 1 (i.e., a probability distribution)
entropy[k] takes the shannon entropy of U1[k]

Hence:
Clear["*Global`*"]
F[r_] := F[r] = 
  DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Table[Range[0, t]/t, {t, 1, r}]]]
S1[k_] := 
 S1[k] = Sort[Select[F[k], Boole[IntegerQ[Denominator[#]/2]] == 1 &]]
S2[k_] := 
 S2[k] = Sort[Select[F[k], Boole[IntegerQ[Denominator[#]/2]] == 0 &]]
P1[k_] := P1[k] = Join[Differences[S1[k]], Differences[S2[k]]]
U1[k_] := U1[k] = P1[k]/Total[P1[k]]
entropy[k_] := entropy[k] = N[Total[-U1[k] Log[2, U1[k]]]]

Question: How do we determine the rate of growth of T=Table[{k,entropy[k]},{k,1,Infinity}] using asymptotic analysis?
Attempt:
We can't actually take infinite values from T, but we could replace Infinity with a large integer.
If we define
T=Join[Table[{k, entropy[k]}, {k, 3, 30}], Table[{10 k, entropy[10 k]}, {k, 3, 10}]]

We could visualize the points using ListPlot

It seems the following function should fit:
nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[
  T, {a + b Log2[x], {a, b}, x]

We end up with (for some reason we get $\ln(x)$ instead of $\log_{2}(x)$):
nlm1=2.72984 Log[E,x]-1.49864

However, when we add additional points to T
 T=Join[Table[{k, entropy[k]}, {k, 3, 30}], Table[{10 k, entropy[10 k]}, {k, 3, 10}],
       Table[{100 k, entropy[100 k]}, {k, 1, 10}]]

We end up with:
nlm1=2.79671 Log[E,x]-1.6831

My guess is we can bound T with the function $3\ln(x)-2$; however, I could only go up to {3000,entropy[3000]} and this is not an asymptotic expansion.
Is there an asymptotic expansion we can use on Table[{k, entropy[k]}, {k, 3, Infinity}?
